# how to write route if I want to use query parameters in string and want to direct everything after search* to a function in contoller?

Tags: cakephp

Router::connect('/form/search*', array('controller' => 'Mycontoller', 'action' => 'search'));

I am really confused about this. I have query parameters in my URL for eg. localhost:8888/Search?srchTxt=Val.

I need to route everything from Search to a method in the controller. How can I do that in route.php file in CakePHP? is there another way I can accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

`$routes->connect('/Search', ['controller' => 'Others', 'action' => 'my_action']);`

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#routes-configuration

everything after question mark (?) is accessible thru `$this->request->query()`

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#query-string-parameters